# Concerning Waiting Times for a Poisson Process and the Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, gamma-distribution

**The Statement of the Problem**

A certain scientific theory supposes that mistakes in cell division occur according to a Poisson process with rate $2.5$ per year, and that an individual dies when $196$ such mistakes have occurred. Assuming this theory, find the probability that an individual dies before age $67.2$.

**What I've Figured Out**

Ok, so, an individual's lifetime is given by the random variable $S_{196}$, i.e. the waiting time until the $196$th cell division. It follows that this random variable has a gamma distribution with parameters $196$ and $2.5$. So, all I have to do is calculate the cdf of this gamma distribution below $67.2$, i.e.

$$ \mathbb P(S_{196} < 67.2) $$

where

$$S_{196} \sim  \Gamma(196, 2.5).$$

Naturally, I'm using software for this computation, and I'm getting some strange numbers back. I believe the answer should be $0.02275$, which makes sense, but I'm not getting very close to that. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, so if anyone can help, it'd be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In the old days one would have used a normal approximation.Not great, but then the model is not necessarily very precise.

Comment: Ha. Well, even using a normal approximation, I'm having the same problem. Although, I am beginning to think that $0.02275$ is not actually the right answer...

Comment: Number of errors at $t=67.2$ is $Poisson(168)$ which yields std of almost $13$ which puts $196$ a little over $2$ standard deviations away, so $2.3\%$ sounds about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little crude, perhaps, but let's use the normal approximation. Our "life" random variable $W$ is the sum of $196$ exponentially distributed random variables, each with mean $\frac{1}{2.5}$ and variance $\frac{1}{(2.5)^2}$. We are invited to assume these are independent.

Thus $W$ has mean  $\frac{196}{2.5}$, that is, $78.4$.

The standard deviation of $W$ is $\sqrt{196/(2.5)^2}$, which is $5.6$.

Note that $67.2$ is exactly $2$ standard deviation units below the mean. For a normal, the probability of being $2$ or more standard deviation units below the mean is $\approx 0.02275$.

Comment: Oh, right. Interestingly, this method is actually giving closer answers to what I'm finding. So, now, of course, I don't know if using the gamma is not expected (possibly because it requires software), or if I just did it completely wrong.

Comment: That the $0.02275$ matches your expectations is too much of a coincidence. It seems clear that normal approximation was intended. Actually, I remembered $0.0228$, but interpolation shows $0.02275$ is closer. (However, giving so many significant figures to what is after all an approximation, with $n$ not very large, is probably not reasonable.)

Comment: Agreed. And, indeed, R gave me $0.02275013$ when I used the normal cdf. Thanks, André!

Comment: The skew of $W$ is $\frac 2{sqrt{196}}=\frac 1 7$, while the skew of $Poisson(168)$ (alternative approximation that looks at number of errors at $t=67.2$) is $\approx \frac 1{13}$, so normal approximation should, at least superficially, be better in the latter scenario.